# ordered version of unordered_map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, hashmap, unordered-map

In my following program I'm currently using `unordered_map` just because I wanted O(1) search/insert time. But now I wanted the items to be ordered. Sorting it every time is very inefficient. What are my alternatives ? I read that `hash_map` does the job but the articles i read are very confusing or rather complicated for me to understand. What is the complexity of insert/search for `hash_map` and is it really ordered ? If so, is it defined in C++0x and how can I implement it ? If not what else can I use ? Thanks.

```
include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t & seed, const T & v)
{
  std::hash<T> hasher;
  seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

template <typename C> struct ContainerHasher
{
  typedef typename C::value_type value_type;
  inline size_t operator()(const C & c) const
  {
    size_t seed = 0;
    for (typename C::const_iterator it = c.begin(), end = c.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
      hash_combine<value_type>(seed, *it);
    }
    return seed;
  }
};


typedef std::set<int> my_set;
typedef std::vector<int> my_vector;
typedef std::unordered_map<my_set, my_vector, ContainerHasher<std::set<int>>> my_map;
typedef my_map::iterator m_it;

void print(my_map& data)
{
        for( m_it it(data.begin()) ; it!=data.end(); ++it)
        {
                cout << "Key : ";
                copy(it->first.begin(), it->first.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
                cout << " => Value: ";
                copy (it->second.begin(),it->second.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
                cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------\n";
}

int main()
{
   my_vector v1,v2,v3;
  for(int i = 1; i<=10; ++i)
   {
      v1.push_back(i);
      v2.push_back(i+10);
      v3.push_back(i+20);
   }

   my_set s1(v3.begin(),v3.begin()+3);
   my_set s2(v1.begin(),v1.begin()+3);
   my_set s3(v2.begin(),v2.begin()+3);

   my_map m1;

   m1.insert(make_pair(s1,v1));
   m1.insert(make_pair(s2,v2));
   m1.insert(make_pair(s3,v3));

   print(m1);
   my_set s4(v3.begin(),v3.begin()+3);

   m_it it = m1.find(s4);

   if(it != m1.end())
   {
      cout << endl << "found" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << endl << "Not found" << endl;
   }
}
```

EDIT:

I was using `std::map` before but I have large number of items (in millions). So even if the number of items are so large do you all recommend `map` if I want it ordered ?

Comment: You can’t have your cake and eat it too. If you give up order, you can get speed O(1) insert/find of unordered_map; if you want order, you get either insert, or find, or both slower.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a regular `std::map`. Note this means you need ordering instead of hashing.

An `unordered_map` *is* a `hash_map`, by the way. "Unordered" just captures the conceptual difference rather than the implementation difference, so it's a better name.

Comment: I added some contents to the question. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @Sunil: You don't usually choose map or unordered_map based on the number of elements you plan to store in it.  You usually choose the container based on the operations you need to perform.  If most of the operations are random access then unordered_map is likely better.  If most of the operations require sequential access then map is likely better.  Note that map uses std::less<Key> by default to store its elements in order.  You can override that with a third template parameter (e.g. std::map<Key, Value, MyComparer>) if you need a different order.

Comment: @Sean : Neither `map` nor `unordered_map` provide random access.

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm referring to how the map or unordered_map are used, not the kind of iterators they provide.

Comment: @Sean : I understand that; I only meant to point out that your terminology is confusing.

Comment: @ildjarn: Yeah, I thought of that too but I couldn't think of a better way to say what I was trying to say in less than 600 characters.

Comment: @Sunil: Either you want them ordered or not. How many you have isn't really relevant, in general. How often do you want them ordered?

Comment: @Sunil: Then you want a `std::map`, which maintains ordering.

Answer (score 1):

IF you need the sorted order frequently enough, then I'd suggest switching to `map` which is an ordered container. Insert and find are now logarithmic in complexity but the container comes sorted by default.

Answer (score 0):

To keep elements ordered while inserting, you need to use (ordered) map, it is designed with asymptotically log(N) worst case insertion complexity, the best result for any comparison-based ordering algorithms.

To provide fast (average) access to existing elements you may  *probably* want to use unordered (hash) map.

If both cases are significant, you may use *both* maps, manually or creating some wrapper container class incapsulating map and ordered map simultaniously.

However, this solution may be useful only if read operations are (significantly!) more frequent than write ones, and has some drawbacks as memory consumption (which may lead to performance degradation due to  cache and page swapping problems). So some experiments and profiling needed with this solution anyway.

Also, if your ordering has some specifics, for instance, your elements are ordered by some "rate" values from a small set (say, 1,2,...10), specific ordering algorithms may be better than map (as this ordering may not need to be comparison-based)

**[edit]** (My last example with ordering by small range values, strictly speaking, is incompatable with possible using of std::map since for large amount of elements it apparently doesn't produce strict weak order. I don't remove it as it may be sometimes useful case in some applications)